# Designate installation on OpenStack failed

Tags: ubuntu, internal-dns, openstack

While trying to install designate on OpenStack Victoria on Ubuntu 20.04 using this guide
https://docs.openstack.org/designate/victoria/install/install-ubuntu.html

I'm getting this error

```
Updating Pools Configuration
****************************
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 CRITICAL designate [designate-manage - - - - -] Unhandled error: oslo_messaging.rpc.client.RemoteError: Remote error: CantStartEngineError No sql_connection parameter is established
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 165, in _process_incoming\n    res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 309, in dispatch\n    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 229, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/rpc.py", line 238, in exception_wrapper\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/central/service.py", line 2277, in find_pool\n    return self.storage.find_pool(context, criterion)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/central/service.py", line 227, in storage\n    self._storage = storage.get_storage(storage_driver)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/storage/__init__.py", line 36, in get_storage\n    return cls()\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/storage/impl_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 40, in __init__\n    super(SQLAlchemyStorage, self).__init__()\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/base.py", line 72, in __init__\n    self.engine = session.get_engine(self.get_name())\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 47, in get_engine\n    facade = _create_facade_lazily(cfg_group)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 38, in _create_facade_lazily\n    _FACADES[cache_name] = session.EngineFacade(\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 1293, in __init__\n    self._factory._start(\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 508, in _start\n    self._setup_for_connection(\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 531, in _setup_for_connection\n    raise exception.CantStartEngineError(\n', 'oslo_db.exception.CantStartEngineError: No sql_connection parameter is established\n'].
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/bin/designate-manage", line 10, in <module>
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     sys.exit(main())
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/cmd/manage.py", line 123, in main
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     fn(*fn_args)
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/manage/pool.py", line 145, in update
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     pool = self.central_api.find_pool(
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/central/rpcapi.py", line 343, in find_pool
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     return self.client.call(context, 'find_pool', criterion=criterion)
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 509, in call
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     return self.prepare().call(ctxt, method, **kwargs)
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 175, in call
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     self.transport._send(self.target, msg_ctxt, msg,
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 123, in _send
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     return self._driver.send(target, ctxt, message,
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 652, in send
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     return self._send(target, ctxt, message, wait_for_reply, timeout,
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 644, in _send
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate     raise result
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate oslo_messaging.rpc.client.RemoteError: Remote error: CantStartEngineError No sql_connection parameter is established
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 165, in _process_incoming\n    res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 309, in dispatch\n    return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 229, in _do_dispatch\n    result = func(ctxt, **new_args)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/rpc.py", line 238, in exception_wrapper\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/central/service.py", line 2277, in find_pool\n    return self.storage.find_pool(context, criterion)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/central/service.py", line 227, in storage\n    self._storage = storage.get_storage(storage_driver)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/storage/__init__.py", line 36, in get_storage\n    return cls()\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/storage/impl_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 40, in __init__\n    super(SQLAlchemyStorage, self).__init__()\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/base.py", line 72, in __init__\n    self.engine = session.get_engine(self.get_name())\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 47, in get_engine\n    facade = _create_facade_lazily(cfg_group)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 38, in _create_facade_lazily\n    _FACADES[cache_name] = session.EngineFacade(\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 1293, in __init__\n    self._factory._start(\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 508, in _start\n    self._setup_for_connection(\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 531, in _setup_for_connection\n    raise exception.CantStartEngineError(\n', 'oslo_db.exception.CantStartEngineError: No sql_connection parameter is established\n'].
2021-06-04 18:35:56.634 2275260 ERROR designate
```

Here are the logs for designate

```
root@openstack:/etc/designate# tail /var/log/designate/designate-
designate-agent.log    designate-api.log      designate-central.log  
root@openstack:/etc/designate# tail /var/log/designate/designate-agent.log 
2021-06-03 16:08:51.127 2080278 INFO designate.agent.handler [-] Agent masters: []
2021-06-03 16:08:51.130 2080278 INFO designate.metrics [-] Statsd disabled
2021-06-03 16:08:51.141 2080278 INFO designate.service [-] Starting agent service (version: 11.0.0)
2021-06-03 16:08:51.141 2080278 INFO designate.utils [-] Opening TCP Listening Socket on 0.0.0.0:5358
2021-06-03 16:08:51.141 2080278 INFO designate.utils [-] Opening UDP Listening Socket on 0.0.0.0:5358
2021-06-03 16:08:51.142 2080278 INFO designate.backend.agent_backend.impl_bind9 [-] Started bind9 backend
2021-06-03 16:08:51.164 2080278 INFO designate.service [req-82426d68-7768-46cf-a4e2-6858015e98b9 - - - - -] _handle_tcp thread started
2021-06-03 16:08:51.165 2080278 INFO designate.service [req-82426d68-7768-46cf-a4e2-6858015e98b9 - - - - -] _handle_udp thread started

root@openstack:/etc/designate# tail /var/log/designate/designate-api.log 
2021-06-04 16:52:01.261 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-459cfdd5-8791-4031-a056-f5a9ecfe2dea - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET /v2/zones HTTP/1.1" status: 503  len: 434 time: 0.0057116
2021-06-04 17:31:41.646 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-45c72086-5a93-453e-83e6-8c9a889efe30 - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET / HTTP/1.1" status: 200  len: 312 time: 0.0010707
2021-06-04 17:31:41.650 2080402 CRITICAL keystonemiddleware.auth_token [req-45c72086-5a93-453e-83e6-8c9a889efe30 - - - - -] Unable to validate token: Unable to establish connection to https://127.0.0.1:35357: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb047d02e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED')): keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to https://127.0.0.1:35357: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb047d02e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED'))
2021-06-04 17:31:41.651 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-45c72086-5a93-453e-83e6-8c9a889efe30 - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET /v2/zones HTTP/1.1" status: 503  len: 434 time: 0.0027246
2021-06-04 17:32:18.532 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-aadb869e-8c80-470a-9814-54b74823f060 - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET / HTTP/1.1" status: 200  len: 312 time: 0.0015867
2021-06-04 17:32:18.538 2080402 CRITICAL keystonemiddleware.auth_token [req-aadb869e-8c80-470a-9814-54b74823f060 - - - - -] Unable to validate token: Unable to establish connection to https://127.0.0.1:35357: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb0492b100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED')): keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to https://127.0.0.1:35357: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb0492b100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED'))
2021-06-04 17:32:18.540 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-aadb869e-8c80-470a-9814-54b74823f060 - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET /v2/zones HTTP/1.1" status: 503  len: 434 time: 0.0040829
2021-06-04 18:11:38.608 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-42aeb27c-e929-4440-aa4a-dba68ed89c66 - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET / HTTP/1.1" status: 200  len: 312 time: 0.0028553
2021-06-04 18:11:38.616 2080402 CRITICAL keystonemiddleware.auth_token [req-42aeb27c-e929-4440-aa4a-dba68ed89c66 - - - - -] Unable to validate token: Unable to establish connection to https://127.0.0.1:35357: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb047d0760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED')): keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to https://127.0.0.1:35357: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb047d0760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED'))
2021-06-04 18:11:38.618 2080402 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-42aeb27c-e929-4440-aa4a-dba68ed89c66 - - - - -] 127.0.0.1 "GET /v2/zones HTTP/1.1" status: 503  len: 434 time: 0.0056593


root@openstack:/etc/designate# tail /var/log/designate/designate-central.log 
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/designate/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 38, in _create_facade_lazily
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     _FACADES[cache_name] = session.EngineFacade(
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 1293, in __init__
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self._factory._start(
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 508, in _start
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self._setup_for_connection(
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 531, in _setup_for_connection
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     raise exception.CantStartEngineError(
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall oslo_db.exception.CantStartEngineError: No sql_connection parameter is established
2021-06-04 18:40:35.151 2080147 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall
```

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: *No sql_connection parameter is established* seems to indicate that you forgot the database connection parameters in a config file. Perhaps the Designate config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the installation guide on openstack official website we were having issues regarding database connectivity along with some missing packages.

[OpenStack Docs: Install and configure for Ubuntu](https://docs.openstack.org/designate/victoria/install/install-ubuntu.html)

But following this link the installation was completed without the above errors

[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS : OpenStack Victoria : Configure Designate](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=openstack_victoria4&f=2)

Still facing some issues but the ones related to question are solved, thanks @berndbausch for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Problem still exists a year later on an OpenStack Yoga installation.

The way I eventually fixed it was restarting the designate-api and designate-central before trying to update the pool.

I would theorize the services started somehow upon installation or something with an invalid db config, then when trying to update the pool it fails, then after restarting -api and -central there is a valid config so it comes up.

"systemctl restart designate-api" and also central.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`No sql_connection parameter is established` appears when `[database] connection = mysql+pymysql://designate:password@10.0.0.30/designate` is not exist in .conf file.

This link

https://docs.openstack.org/designate/victoria/install/install-ubuntu.html

does not mention to add `connection = mysql+pymqsql://designate:password@10.0.0.30/designate` in configuration file, but the below one does.